# Why Go takes so much CPU to build a package?

Tags: go

I have download a golang package from github. it is in middle size. when compiling it from source, my computor gets slow down for i have more than one golang compile process and it takes much of the cpu.

how does golang make it to do concurrent compile?
any params to turn the number of cpu it use when compile?

Comment: While the question _may_ have been flagged as off-topic, it's a genuine question from a genuine programmer who has a compilation issue with Go. It might be not written in the best King's English, but it's perfectly understandable. And the answer below — the only one — explains *exactly* what needs to be done to fix this compilation issue. So: my question is, why was this question flagged as off-topic? Aren't programmers allowed to ask why their compilers don't work, and try to get a solution to make them work in their own environment?

Answer (score 4):

Go is using a lot of CPU because it's trying to build as fast as possible, like any other compiler. It may also be because you're using a package that is using cgo, which can drastically increase compiling times as compiling medium to large C libraries is often quite intensive.

You can control the number of processes Go is using by setting the `GOMAXPROCS` environment variable. Such as `GOMAXPROCS=1 go get ...` to limit Go to only use 1 process (and thus only 1 CPU core). This however does not affect the number of processes used by external compilers that cgo may invoke.

If you need further CPU control, on Unix based systems you can use the `nice` command to change the priority of processes such that other programs have higher CPU priority, making your computer less sluggish.

Comment: I find it very sad that this question was flagged as off-topic; I believe it's perfectly legitimate for a programmer to ask why their compiler is not working. I had the same issue myself — because I'm working inside a virtual box (over which I have no control) which only allows 25 processes to be simultaneously used. Go quickly exhausts that with a simple `go mod tidy` — it never comes near to cgo compiling :) But thanks to your simple trick, everything works for me. And it's not *that* slow — after all, the host machine has 32 cores and 64GB...